# BackgroundWorker – Waiting for it to finish or a timeout elapses

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, backgroundworker

I have a web page which is made up of a form for data entry and a panel for displaying the results. This page is written in VB.Net and the website hosting it is in ASP.Net.

Normal usage of the page is as follows:

1. The user inputs the form with some data/filters
2. The user presses the button "Search"
3. A `BackgroundWorker` starts finding the solutions

The BackgroundWorker instance is stored in a static variable, as I don't care about multi-user scenarios, but I'm not tied to this choice and I can change this. Also, the search process is asynchronous, but I really don't need to display anything while it's in progess.
The BackgroundWorker stores the result in a `SolutionStorage` object.

My goal is the following.
When the BackgroundWorker ends, the solutions found must be shown on the page. However, if after a fixed amount of time (currently, three minutes) it's still running, I want to terminate it and display the solutions present in the SolutionStorage in that moment.
The code goes as follows.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  If Not IsNothing(worker) Then
    worker.CancelAsync()
  End If
  worker = New BackgroundWorker()
  worker.WorkerReportsProgress = False
  worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
  AddHandler worker.DoWork, AddressOf workerDo
  AddHandler worker.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf workerComplete
End Sub


Protected Sub search(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles submitButton.Click
  worker.RunWorkerAsync()
  Thread.Sleep(180 * 1000)
  If worker.IsBusy Then
    worker.CancelAsync()
    Dim solutions = repository.getSolutions()
    '' Display solutions
    If (solutions.Count > 0) Then
      SolutionsRepeater.DataBind()
    End If

  End If
End Sub

Protected Sub workerDo()
  '  Collect data from the form
  '  Build the SolutionStorage
  '  Start the search
End Sub


Protected Sub workerComplete(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) 
  '' Display solutions
  If (solutions.Count > 0) Then
    SolutionsRepeater.DataBind()
  End If
End sub


Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  If Not IsNothing(worker) Then
    worker.CancelAsync()
  End If
  worker = New BackgroundWorker()
  worker.WorkerReportsProgress = False
  worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
  AddHandler worker.DoWork, AddressOf workerDo
  AddHandler worker.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf workerComplete
End Sub
```

Is this a correct way of doing things? Is this the better way of doing things?

Answer (score 0):

Locking down an asp .net thread with a sleep call for 3 minutes is not a very good solution.

I would recommend you to build a background system that could do search in the background so your asp .net pages returns immediately. Then you could refresh your page every 10 seconds to
see if the search is still running, finish or failed.

Here is a little trick you might be able to use, but it has some limitations and warnings:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/

Read the comments to see the warnings and limitations.

But since you don't care about multi user support, and I assume the number of visits to your page is very limited, I can't see a direct problem with your current solution. But as soon as you expand it, it might cause you some problems.

Comment: Here the main problem is: the generated thread _won't stop_! The page displays the solutions find at the moment the timeout elapses, as I wanted. But why does the thread go on?

I _am_ concerned about multi_user scenarios. There are 20 people around the world that access this page 30 times a day each.